# Trigger input event of text box when assigned ng model from another method angular

Tags: angular

It it possible to trigger input event of text box when assigned ng-model value is assigned from another method.

```
<p><input
type="text"
[(ngModel)]="testValue"
(input)="modelupdated(testValue)"/></p>


<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">
Create template modal</button></p>
```

Typescript:

```
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
   this.testValue ="test";
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, Object.assign({}, { class: 'modal-sm' }));
}
```

Change event :

`modelupdated(testValue) {
     console.log('from change');
     console.log(testValue);
  }`

What i am looking for, is it possible to trigger the input text field's input/change method when the modal gets opened or after an API response ?

Comment: I would suggest a reactive form to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a reactive way of doing this,

```
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formbuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formbuilder.group({
      text: ["abc"]
    });
    this.form.controls['text'].valueChanges.subscribe(data=>{
      console.log('valuechanged' ,data);
    })
  }
  modelupdated(event) {
    console.log(this.text);
  }

  buttonClicked() {
    this.form.patchValue({
      text:'123'
    }) 
  }
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input
type="text"
formControlName="text"
/>
</form>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elormc)

Comment: @boredbear153 did this solution helped you?